# ¿Cómo actualizar una tabla de la base de datos?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Estoy empezando con Python 3.4 y no he logrado que el programa me actualice la base de datos, cuando trate de usar `import mysql` me sacaba error, entonces encontré esta otra forma de hacerlo, no obtengo ningún error pero no actualiza la base de datos.

Adjunto una imágen de la base de datos y el programa con el que he tratado de actualizara sin éxito:

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql

# Open database connection
print("paso1 - Abre base de datos")
db = pymysql.connect("localhost", port=3306, user="root",
                     passwd="easy", db="easyweb" )

print("paso2 - Define cursor")
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
print("paso3 - Genera SQL")
sql = """INSERT INTO encabezados_csc(nro_csc_enc,
   id_csc_enc, fec_csc_enc, hor_csc_enc, codadm_csc_enc,
   codemp_csc_enc,mur_ext_csc_enc)
   VALUES ('1', '79100101', 20170711, '11.21','A1','E1','E' 2000)"""

print("paso4 - sigue try:")
try:
    #Execute the SQL command
    print("paso5 - ejecuta SQL")
    cursor.execute(sql)
    print("paso6 - Fin ejecución SQL")
    # Commit your changes in the database
    print("paso7 - Ejecuta cambios sql")
    db.commit()
except:
    print("paso8 - Reversa cambios sql")
    # Rollback in case there is any error
    db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te da algún error? ¿Se conecta a la base de datos correctamente? Justo después de `db = pymysql.connect(.... ` haz `print(db)` ha ver que te retorna.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responderme, hice lo que me dijiste y sacó lo siguiente:<pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x00000000038D2668>

Comment: Vale eso indica que la conexión se realiza correctamente. Realiza el `cursor.execute(sql)` antes del `try` para no ocultar los errores. Me acabo de dar cuenta pero creo que tu query es incorrecta. El último valor a insertar es:  `... ,'E' 2000)`? ¿No debería ser `'E 2000'`? ¿De qué tipo es la columna `mur_ext_csc_enc`?

Comment: hola como estas? efectivamente sobra un campo, pero lo modifico y le pongo la instrucción  print (db) después de ejecutar el sql y saca lo siguiente:paso1 - Abre base de datos
paso3 - Genera SQL
<pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x0000000004283278>
paso4 - sigue try:
paso5 - ejecuta SQL
paso8 - Reversa cambios sql  . Reviso la base de datos y está vacia.

Comment: Freddy ejecuta la consulta y el `commit` fuera del `try` o imprime el error en el `except`, claramente hay un error y se entra en el `except` (te imprime la linea `paso8 - ....`). Quita el `try-except`, estás, ocultando la excepción con ello, y muestra el error que te da. Ten en cuenta que si se produce **cualquier error sin importar cual dentro del `try`** se ejecuta el código del `except`, es decir haces un rollback de la base de datos y logicamente no se agregan ningun dato a ella ya que el `try` ha fallado.  Saludos.

Comment: La linea que está causando el error es claramente `cursor.execute(sql)`. La consulta está fallando por algo, esto puede deberse a muchas cosas, desde que tu sentencia sea inválida, a que estes proporcionando un valor que no coincide con el tipo de la columna, a distinto número de columnas, que una columna no exista, que no tengas permisos de escritura, etc. Por eso debes ejecutar esa linea fuera del `try` y mostrar el error, es seguro que te dará uno. Saludos.

Comment: Si señor tienes toda la razón el problema no es del código sino de la definición de la base de datos, te agradezco mucho tu ayuda, no sabes todo el tiempo que llevaba buscando la solución.Gracias.

Comment: De nada Freddy, si todo esta solucionado voy a iniciar el cierre de la pregunta ya que el error no es reproducible al estar en la base de datos y no en el código. También puedes eliminarla tu directamente. Saludos.

Comment: Si señor estaba tratando de buscar la forma de aceptar la respuesta, pero me perdí la vez pasada lo pude hacer pero esta vez no encuentro por donde

Comment: Es que no hay respuesta, solo son comentarios. No te preocupes, como digo la pregunta no es reproducible por lo que no será de ayuda a otros usuarios y en estos casos se cierra por este motivo. Como comentas (excepto por lo del valor de sobra) no hay error en el código. Recuerda siempre usar el try-except con cuidado durante el desarrollo, porque puedes ocultar excepciones y volverte loco buscando. Saludos.

Comment: Listo de verdad muchas gracias y disculpa por la pregunta estaba mal enfocada, pero no me había dado cuenta, nuevamente gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una buena practica es captura la `exception` y luego imprimirla para tener una idea más acabada de lo que le pasa a tu código. Por ejemplo:

```
try:
    with db.cursor() as cursor:
         cursor.execute(sql)
         db.commit()

except Exception as exc:
    print("Se ha producido un error. El error es %s" % exc)
```

De esta manera podes imprimir el error y ver por donde encarar la solución para que tu código funciones. El `with` que utilice te permite cerrar la conexión cuando sale del bloque de codigo.
Te sugiero que mires en este link de github el README que tiene un ejemplo fácil de seguir:

https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL